# Filling a field with a random string from a list in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I need to fill a field with false string data from a given list randomly. There are `rand` and  `randf` functions generating random numbers. There is a similar (not identical) question: [Updating attribute field with random string value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/203729/29431). But it doesn't meet my need. Also, the answer in that post does not work as expected.

How can I fill the field with a random string from a list, preferably using existing functions?

Pseudo-expression I need: `randstr(['A', 'B', 'C'])`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can build the array, build a random index and extract its value

```
array('a','b','c')[rand(0,2)]
```

Comment: less quotes : `string_to_array('A,B,C', ',')[rand(0, 2)]`

Comment: @J.Monticolo  but 41% more characters :-)

Comment: For a short list of strings it is quite short. I didn't imagine using like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not an expression expert. My solution uses a custom function.

Function definition:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import random

@qgsfunction(args=-1, group='Custom')
def randstr(in_list, feature, parent):
    return random.choice(in_list)
```

Usage:

```
randstr('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try an expression like this:

```
with_variable('stringlist',array('string_a','string_b','string_c'),
array_get(@stringlist,rand(0,array_length(@stringlist)-1)))
```

Explanation: First set up an array as variable, so you only have to build your lookup-array once. Next we pickup a random position from this array using `array_get()` combined with `rand()`. The minimum value is 0, as the array is 0 based. Because of that, we also need to remove 1 from `array_length()`, which is not 0 based, serving as maximum value.